# Compare two datetime values with pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I would like to make the following comparison between two datetime values using pandas:

```
for i1, df1_row in df1.iterrows():
    for i2, df2_row in df2.iterrows():
        if df1['time'] >= df2['time']:
            print 'Time 1 greater than time 2'
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to Series
```

Both dates have been formatted the same way using pd.to_datetime. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: please provide output of df1.describe() and df2.describe()

Comment: Do you mean the output of df1.dtypes? They are both listed as object, and have been formatted using df1['time']=pd.to_datetime(df1['time']).

Comment: Don't use iterrows (almost ever, and definitely not in this case).  Just do `df1['time']>=df2['time']` (w/o iterrows) which should work if they are of same type and have same index.  Btw, 'object' probably just means string here.  You probably want to convert to proper datetime with `pd.to_datetime()`

Comment: You really need some sample data, especially if you are using different indices.